# Is there any possibility to return query upon previously queried data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, select

I have businesses table in mysql. I am using node js as server side. 
I have businesses table which has amounth of data about businesses and I have index_table which has more than 25 fields and all of them are indexed like city, state, categories, hasEmail, hasPhone, hasFax, annual_revenue, employee_count etc.

The question is when user visits my website, they have to choose couple of categories

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database.index_table WHERE category = "Convenience Store" or category="Bars"
```

Since category field is indexed, this returns really fast. But when they want to add more filters like city, state, hasWebsite query becomes like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database.index_table WHERE category = "Convenience Store" and state="IL" and hasWebsite=1;
```

The problem here is I have to show total count of filtered businesses to user whenever they choose a new filter. In this case I can end up with WHERE which can have 20 condition and 20 AND. So it becomes really hard to show COUNT(*) really fast. For example when they send only two categories I am fetching the count but when they choose two categories and one more filter I also have to send "WHERE category = ''" part again in the query. This looks really inefficient.

The question is, is there a way to select data from mysql and than is there a way to select data upon that previously selected data? This is like piping and filtering data? Since I have 29 million rows in my index_table I do not think filtering them with Javascript is meaningful as well.

If anyone can help me with this, ı would appreciate that. Otherwise I am going to be unemployed.

Comment: You need something like `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Isn't it about the count? I need data core after category selection, than I am going to export city filter from that data.

Comment: Unless the data set is very large, it might be more efficient to return the whole data set as xml or json and then filter and count in your application code - I always think this example is instructive: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/GFbAs

Comment: @Strawberry.Okey new question arrises here. Lets say I have 300K data retrieved from first filtering from database. Retrieving other filters with Javascript json actions on data or sending another query which has more than 20 where condition. Which one is faster?